# How to write Pandas output into multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a scraper using Selenium and then write data to a CSV file.
Each time I run the script below it produces a data.csv but output was re-written on the same row over and over again resulting in only single row.

How do you write output to a separate rows ?

```
import pandas as pd

elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-listing-row")
for ii in elem:
    pname = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
    print('pname: ' + pname)
    psku = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-code').text
    print('psku: ' + psku)
    thumb = ii.find_element_by_class_name('scaleAll').get_attribute('src')
    print('thumb: ' + thumb)
    link = ii.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print('address: ' + link)
    raw_data = {'Product_Name': [pname],
        'Product_SKU': [psku],
        'Product_ImageURL': [thumb],
        'Product _URL': [link]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Product_Name', 'Product_SKU', 'Product_ImageURL', 'Product _URL'])
    df.to_csv (r'/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
raw_data = {'Product_Name': [pname],
    'Product_SKU': [psku],
    'Product_ImageURL': [thumb],
    'Product _URL': [link]}
```

for each `elem`, you overwrite `raw_data`. Instead you can do something like that:

```
#initialize a list for your data
raw_data = []
for ii in elem:
    pname = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
    print('pname: ' + pname)
    psku = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-code').text
    print('psku: ' + psku)
    thumb = ii.find_element_by_class_name('scaleAll').get_attribute('src')
    print('thumb: ' + thumb)
    link = ii.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print('address: ' + link)
    raw_data_elem = {'Product_Name': pname,
        'Product_SKU': psku,
        'Product_ImageURL': thumb,
        'Product _URL': link}
    #add row to list
    raw_data.append(raw_data_elem)
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Product_Name', 'Product_SKU',   
        'Product_ImageURL', 'Product _URL'])
df.to_csv (r'/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it in [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) mode:

```py
import pandas as pd

elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-listing-row")
header = True
for ii in elem:
    pname = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
    psku = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-code').text
    thumb = ii.find_element_by_class_name('scaleAll').get_attribute('src')
    link = ii.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    raw_data = {'Product_Name': [pname],
        'Product_SKU': [psku],
        'Product_ImageURL': [thumb],
        'Product _URL': [link]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Product_Name', 'Product_SKU', 'Product_ImageURL', 'Product _URL'])
    df.to_csv (r'/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/data.csv', mode="a", header=header)
    header = False
```

This will add a header to your csv only on the first iteration, then append all the new rows to the file.

Alternatively, you could make the DataFrame once and then save it:

```py
import pandas as pd

elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-listing-row")

raw_data = {'Product_Name': [],
        'Product_SKU': [],
        'Product_ImageURL': [],
        'Product_URL': []
}

for ii in elem:
    raw_data['Product_Name'].append(
        ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
    )
    raw_data['Product_SKU'].append(
        ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-code').text
    )
    raw_data['Product_ImageURL'].append(
        ii.find_element_by_class_name('scaleAll').get_attribute('src')
    )
    raw_data['Product_URL'].append(
        ii.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df.to_csv (r'/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

change to `df.to_csv(r'/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/data.csv', mode='a', header=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to append every element into the list.

This is an example. Inside the loop you retrieve element and append the result to your list that has to be included in the Dataframe out of the loop:

```
import pandas as pd

    raw_data = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        element = {'item': i }
        raw_data.append(element)

    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['item'])
    df.to_csv ('./data.csv')
```